# sending a notification to specific online users

Tags: javascript, php, windows, notifications

I've written some code that should send push notifications to specific users when they are online, under specific circumstances.
I need help optimizing and fixing this, as it only works sometimes, and I believe it is putting a pretty big toll on my server.

The system this works on is a ticket system. When a new ticket is assigned, it is suppose to send a push notification to any user with admin powers, and then when a user is 'assigned' to a ticket, it should also send them a push notification. I had some issues with the program sending multiple notifications to the same user, but was able to fix that, but now it only sends them somtimes (I am unable to find a pattern as to when it actually works)

Here is my code:

Javascript, the actual notifs:

```
    <script>
function notifyMe() {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
  else {
    var notification = new Notification('You\'ve been added to a ticket!', {
      icon: 'images/trg.jpg',
      body: "You have just been added to a ticket, please check the ticket system for more details.",
      priority: "2",
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("http://example");      
    };

  }

}
</script>
<script>
function notifyAdmin() {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
  else {
    var notification = new Notification('A new ticket has been added!', {
      icon: 'images/trg.jpg',
      body: "A new ticket has been added!",
      priority: "2",
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("http://example");      
    };

  }

}
</script>
```

My php, all the if statements and when it should send etc. The notifications are sent via a function (sendNotify()), which are literally only calling the JavaScript from before.

```
$configs = include("config.php");

        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }

        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$configs['SQL-Database'].';host='.$configs['SQL-Host'].''; 
        $user = $configs['SQL-User']; 
        $password = $configs['SQL-Pass']; 

        $con = mysqli_connect($configs['SQL-Host'], $configs['SQL-User'], $configs['SQL-Pass'], $configs['SQL-Database']) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
        $checkTickets = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE notified='0'");
        $tcheckTickets = mysqli_num_rows($checkTickets);

        if(($tcheckTickets > 0) && ($_SESSION['Level'] >= 2)) {
            try { 
                $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); 
            } catch (PDOException $e) { 
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
            }

            $st = $db->prepare('SELECT UniqueID FROM tickets WHERE notified=0'); 
            $st->execute(); 

            $result = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

            foreach($result as $d){ 
                echo $d['UniqueID'] . "<br/>"; 
                $id = $d['UniqueID']; 
                $st = $db->prepare("UPDATE tickets SET notified=1 WHERE UniqueID=$id"); 
                sendSound();
                sendNotifyAdmin();
                sleep(3);
                $st->execute(); 
            }
        }

        $checkTickets2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE notified='1'");
        $tcheckTickets2 = mysqli_num_rows($checkTickets2);

        if($tcheckTickets2 > 0) {
            try { 
                $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); 
            } catch (PDOException $e) { 
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
            }

            $st = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE notified=1'); 
            $st->execute(); 

            $result = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

            foreach($result as $d){ 
                if(strcmp($d['Assigned'],$_SESSION['Name']) == 0) {
                    echo $d['UniqueID'] . "<br/>"; 
                    $id = $d['UniqueID']; 
                    $st = $db->prepare("UPDATE tickets SET notified=2 WHERE UniqueID=$id");
                    sendSound();
                    sendNotify();
                    sleep(3);
                    $st->execute(); 
                }
            }           
        }
```

This is how it works currently:

When a ticket is submitted, it is given a 0 in the "notified" column in the database. The script I put in earlier is refreshed every few seconds, and first checks for any tickets with `notified` equal to 0, and if any are found, it should send a notification to any user online with admin rights. The script then checks for any `notified` equal to 1, and sends a message to any user that is assigned to the ticket, and then it stops when `notified` is equal to 2.

I am definately open to any systems that make this easier, less load, and actually work properly. I am also open to suggestions on how I can improve my current code to work better.